# Find the closed path of given system of ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Consider the system of ordinary differential equations:
$$\begin{cases}\frac{dx}{dt}=4x^3y^2-x^5y^4\\
\frac{dy}{dt}=x^4y^5+2x^2y^3\end{cases}$$
Then for this system there exist

$1).$ A closed path in $\left \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}|x^2+y^2 \leq 5  \right \}$

$2).$ A closed path in $\left \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}|5<x^2+y^2 \leq 10  \right \}$

$3). $ A closed path in $\left \{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}|x^2+y^2 >10 \right \}$

$4). $ No closed Path in $\mathbb{R^2}$

**solution i tried**- I first find out the $\frac{dy}{dx}$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^2y^3+2y}{4x-x^3y^2}$$

it will become

$$-(x^2y^2+2)ydx+(4-x^2y^2)xdy=0\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\
....................1$$

which is of from $$f_1(xy)ydx+f_2(xy)xdy$$
 after that i find the $I.F$ of $1$ which comes out $$\frac{-1}{6xy}$$
now by multiplying this with $1$ i get $$\frac{1}{6} \left ( xy^2+\frac{2}{x} \right )  dx-\frac{1}{6} \left ( \frac{4}{y}+x^2y \right )dy=0$$
 after solving this i get answer $$\frac{x^2y^2}{12}-\frac{1}{3}\log (\frac{x}{y^2})=c$$

but there is noting related to given option ,where i am making mistake please help

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this problem, it is not necessary to solve a system of differential equations. Use the [Bendixson–Dulac theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bendixson%E2%80%93Dulac_theorem) instead:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=12x^2y^2-5x^4y^4
$$
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=5x^4y^4+6x^2y^2
$$
The function
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial g}{\partial y}=12x^2y^2+6x^2y^2=18x^2y^2,
$$
has the same sign almost everywhere,
therefore, the conditions of the theorem are satisfied. Hence, there are no closed orbits.

Comment: I have no idea for what path he is asking here, can you please elaborate this?

Comment: @TheStudent A closed path, an orbit and a periodic solution are generally the same thing. Different authors use these names with some nuances. This task asks if the system has periodic solutions.

Comment: On wikipedia  they considered $\phi$ function ,but here what you have considered that function?

Comment: @TheStudent Here $\phi(x,y) = 1$

Comment: Thank you  @AVK, now i got the solution,but still i have a question,is there any possibility to get answer from solution I derived?

Comment: @TheStudent There is a mistake somewhere in your solution. The picture of the phase plane of the original system does not coincide with the curves that you obtained. But if the solution were correct and one could prove that the curves are open, then this would work.

Comment: @AVK  It's simply a sign mistake $-(xy)^2+4\ln \dfrac {y^2}{x}=C$

Comment: @Aryadeva i have $\frac{x}{y^2}$ within log ,but you have $\frac{y^2}{x}$ in log ,so seems no difference in both the answers

Comment: There is a difference... change the log function you will see it @TheStudent mine gives $(xy)^2+4\ln \dfrac x{y^2}=C_0$ There is still a sign difference The Student

Comment: @Aryadeva can you please elaborate this ,yes i have made mistake  here that i considered $\log x$ instead of $\ln|x|$. but i am not getting your point.

Comment: I will add an answer for this @TheStudent

Comment: Thank you @Aryadeva,that will be very helpful for me.

Comment: you're welcome. Check if you can find a sign mistake in your solution. @TheStudent

Answer (score 3):

Starting from this line in your answer:
$$-(x^2y^2+2)ydx+(4-x^2y^2)xdy=0$$
$$-x^2y^2(ydx+xdy)-2ydx+4xdy=0$$
$$-x^2y^2d(xy)-2ydx+4xdy=0$$
Divide by $xy$:
$$-xyd(xy)-2\dfrac {dx}x+4\dfrac {dy}y=0$$
$$-(xy)^2-4\ln x+8\ln y=0$$
$$-(xy)^2+4\ln \dfrac {y^2}{x}=C$$
Or if you prefer:
$$(xy)^2+4\ln \dfrac x{y^2}=C_1$$
Our answers are different. There is a sign difference. This may explain AVK's comment:

*There is a mistake somewhere in your solution. The picture of the phase plane of the original system does not coincide with the curves that you obtained.*

---

Your mistake is here: 
$$\frac{1}{6} \left ( xy^2+\frac{2}{x} \right )  dx-\frac{1}{6} \left ( \frac{4}{y}\color {red}{+x^2y} \right )dy=0$$

The term in red should be negative from the precedent line:
$$-(x^2y^2+2)ydx+(4-x^2y^2)xdy=0$$
You multiply by $-\dfrac 1 {6xy}$:
$$\dfrac 1 {6xy}(x^2y^2+2)ydx-\dfrac 1 {6xy}(4 \color{blue}{-x^2y^2})xdy=0$$

Comment: i am confused now,i tried this question 4 times each time get different result

Comment: You should do the calculation calmly without stress. Ii used exactness to solve this DE with little manipulations. @TheStudent

Comment: I find your mistake and added some lines @TheStudent

Comment: One more question , The solution we find what does this represent ?does this solution we derived can satisfies any condition in options?

Comment: It gives an idea of the phase plane. Sometimes it's easier to sketch the phase plane with this solution. What are the conditions @TheStudent

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

It's worth getting an idea about the field, using a phase plotter, say [here](https://homepages.bluffton.edu/~nesterd/apps/slopefields.html). Once you notice the rough shape of the movements along the paths, you can check for instance that along any path starting in the upper half plane we have $\frac{d y}{d t} > 0$. What can you conclude? What about a path starting in the lower half plane? On the $x$ axis?